# In MediaWiki can external data be rendered into a chart?

Tags: mediawiki

I've got the extensions ExternalData and GoogleCharts installed.

Can External data (e.g., the result of a SQL query from a database) become the numbers for a chart (via any extension e.g. for GoogleCharts)?

Can you point to any page on a wiki that shows the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This worked on a local wiki (so no URL available, sorry).

First add to LocalSettings.php

```
$srfgFormats[] = 'googlepie';
$srfgFormats[] = 'googlebar';
```

In the wiki, create a property of type page called Id Field in List.

Then in the page where you want to show the data:

```
{{#get_db_data:
db=data
|from=MyTable as I 
|where=1 GROUP BY MyField
|limit=999
|order by=COUNT(*) DESC 
|data=Field=MyField,count=COUNT(*)
}}
```

Store the data

```
{{#store_external_table:Is Field in List |Has field={{{Field}}} |Has count={{{count}}}}}
```

Display the stored data excluding the first column as a table

```
{{#ask:[[Is Field in List::{{PAGENAME}}]]|?Has field=Field |?Has count=Count |format=table|mainlabel=-}}
```

Display the stored data excluding the first column as a googlebar

```
{{#ask:[[Is Field in List::{{PAGENAME}}]]|?Has field|?Has count|format=googlebar|mainlabel=-}}
```

Display the stored data excluding the first column as a googlepie

```
{{#ask:[[Is Field in List::{{PAGENAME}}]]|?Has field|?Has count|format=googlepie|mainlabel=-}}
```